# Simple MySQL Join to replace foreign key

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables, tickets and state. Tickets has a foreign key state which corresponds to state.id

```
SELECT tickets.id AS 'Ticket Id', 
       state.description AS 'State'
FROM tickets 
LEFT JOIN state ON tickets.state = state.id
WHERE tickets.id = 1;
```

So if I have a row in tickets with tickets.id = 1 and tickets.state = 1 and I have a row in state with state.id = 1 and state.description = 'Open'

How do I get a result Ticket Id = 1, State = Open?

EDIT: This does work, for some reason the state table was empty...

Comment: "*Simple MySQL Join **to replace foreign key***"?

Comment: `AND state.description = 'open'`? btw, I don't think you need the quotes around your `AS 'state'`, but I'm not sure if it is a problem // best practice to do so.

Comment: Does this query not give you exactly what you're asking for? Can't say for sure without seeing example data, but the `LEFT JOIN` probably isn't needed and an `INNER JOIN` will suffice.

Comment: It gives me NULL for state.description

Comment: @Theveloper If your data is as described, that really shouldn't be. Your query is correct for `tickets.id=1, tickets.state=1, state.id=1, state.description='Open'`

Answer (score 1):

That seems like

```
SELECT tickets.id AS 'Ticket Id', 
       state.description AS 'State'
FROM tickets 
LEFT JOIN state ON tickets.state = state.id
WHERE tickets.id = 1 and state.state = 'open';
```

Comment: I don't want to check whether state is open, that's the whole point... tickets.state is the foreign key to the state table, i need the ticket id with the state description, but with what I have so far state is always null

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like that is what you would get from the query you've written...?

If you want to have the exact result "Ticked Id =1, State = Open" from your db, look into the concat()-function. If you would like to have the states directly into your ticket-table, I would first add a new column, then update that using an update query, then drop the old tickets.state column. Or, maybe what you really need is a view defined using the above mentioned query.

create view ticketstate as SELECT ticket.id ...