# How to use use join to replace foreign key relationship MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to make a simple query that retrieves data from two tables. One table, ForumPosts holds data pertaining to posts in a forum, the other, Users, holds data about users on my system.

The issue I'm having is that when I want to collect data about which users posted which posts.

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> select * from ForumPosts;
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| ID | UserID | Title                                                                       | Post                                                                                                                                       | ImgFile | SubmissionTime      |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | More tests                                                            | tests...                                                                                                          | NULL    | 2019-02-26 01:39:28 |
|  2 |      2 | Another test post                          | tests...                                               | NULL    | 2019-02-26 22:52:26 |
|  3 |      1 | Test post                                      | tests…                                                                                   | NULL    | 2019-03-27 22:10:38 |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

```
mysql> select * from Users;
+----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| ID | Email          | UserName | Password | DateRegistered      |
+----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | test@test.com  | tester   | dank     | 2019-02-26 22:43:26 |
|  2 | test2@test.com | 2tester  | dank     | 2019-02-26 22:43:26 |
+----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I have tried looking at some other posts such as:
[Simple MySQL Join to replace foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282403/simple-mysql-join-to-replace-foreign-key)
And they all seem to be having the same issue as me, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my solution.

This is the query that I'm currently using.

```
select 
    Title, 
    Users.ID as Author, 
    SubmissionTime as Posted 
from ForumPosts
left join 
    Users on ForumPosts.UserID = Users.ID
order by SubmissionTime desc;
```

But what is returned is this:

```
mysql> select 
    ->     Title, 
    ->     UserId as Author, 
    ->     SubmissionTime as Posted 
    -> from ForumPosts
    ->     left join 
    ->     Users on ForumPosts.UserID = Users.ID
    -> order by SubmissionTime desc;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| Title                                                                       | Author | Posted              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| Test post                                      |      1 | 2019-03-27 22:10:38 |
| Another test post                         |      2 | 2019-02-26 22:52:26 |
| More tests                                                            |      1 | 2019-02-26 01:39:28 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

It result lists the foreign keys for the users but I want their associated usernames instead.

I feel like this should be a pretty simple fix, but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: If you want the user names, then that's what you should put in the select list, not the id... And this has nothing to do with foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Users.UserName,` in select statement like below

```
select 
    Title, 
    Users.UserName,
    Users.ID as Author, 
    SubmissionTime as Posted 
from ForumPosts
left join 
    Users on ForumPosts.UserID = Users.ID
order by SubmissionTime desc;
```